# System.ArgumentException: String value can not be converted to a date

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have a web form that uses an Ajax date calendar.  This works fine.  The problem that i have is that when i submit my form i get the following message.

```
'String value can not be converted to a date' .AgendaDate = New SmartDate(txtAgendaDate.Text)
```

Here is my web form that holds the calendar and the associated text box...

```
 <td>
     <asp:TextBox ID="txtAgendaDate" runat="server" ForeColor="Black" ></asp:TextBox>
 </td>
 <td>
     <asp:ImageButton runat="Server" ID="ImageButton1" ImageUrl="~/images/calendarpic.png" 
                AlternateText="Click here to display calendar" />

     <cc1:calendarextender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" 
                     TargetControlID="txtAgendaDate" PopupButtonID="ImageButton1" >
     </cc1:calendarextender>
 </td>
```

I have a class with the associated properties on it for the web form.  The rest of the fields work and submit data to the database except the textfield for the ajax calendar.

Here is my stripped down version for the code for the class and the txtAgendaDate code...

```
#Region " Agenda Variables "

'Declare Variables and data types and set default values
Private mAgendaID As Integer = 0
Private mOrganiser As String = ""
Private mMeeting As String = ""
Private mAgendaDate As SmartDate = New SmartDate()

#End Region

#Region " Constructors "

Public Sub New()
End Sub

Public Sub New(ByVal reader As SafeDataReader)
    '  Public Sub New(ByVal reader As SQLDataReader)

    'Combine variables & property types
    With reader
        mAgendaID = .GetInt32("AgendaID")
        mOrganiser = .GetString("Organiser")
        mMeeting = .GetString("Meeting")
        mAgendaDate = .GetSmartDate("AgendaDate")
    End With
End Sub

#End Region

#Region "Properties"

'Define form field properies so that they can be used when adding the data to the database on the add button is pressed.
Public Property AgendaID() As Integer
    Get
        Return mAgendaID
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As Integer)
        mAgendaID = Value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property Organiser() As String
    Get
        Return mOrganiser
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        mOrganiser = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property Meeting() As String
    Get
        Return mMeeting
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        mMeeting = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property AgendaDate() As SmartDate
    Get
        Return mAgendaDate
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As SmartDate)
        mAgendaDate = Value
    End Set
End Property

#End Region


End Class
```

Here is my command that looks connects to the DB and at the stored procedure and also has the parameters.

```
Public Class Agenda_TempDAL

Public Shared Function AddAgenda_Temp(ByVal Agenda_Temp As Agenda_Temp) As Integer

    'Declare i as integer as 0
    Dim iAgendaID As Integer = 0

    'Database conn, this is linked to the web config file .AppSettings
    Using dbconnection As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("dbconnection"))
        dbconnection.Open()

        'Command to state the stored procedure and the name of the stored procedure
        Using dbcommand As SqlCommand = dbconnection.CreateCommand
            With dbcommand
                .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                .CommandText = "Stored_Proc_Name"

                'Create parameter for AgendaID and output
                Dim oParam As New SqlParameter
                oParam.ParameterName = "@AgendaID"
                oParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
                oParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int

                'Create parameters for the remaining fields
                .Parameters.Add(oParam)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Organiser", Agenda_Temp.Organiser)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Meeting", Agenda_Temp.Meeting)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@AgendaDate", Agenda_Temp.AgendaDate.DBValue)

                'Simply execute the query
                dbcommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

            End With
        End Using
    End Using

    'Need to return the agendaID as an integer.
    Return iAgendaID

End Function
End Class
```

And here is the code behind the button ion the web page.  This is the page that causes the error based on the property / field.  The problem lies on this line...

```
.AgendaDate = New SmartDate(txtAgendaDate.Text)
```

The whole code for the button is here...

```
Protected Sub btnAddAgendaTemplate_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As    System.EventArgs) Handles btnAddAgendaTemplate.Click

    'This works alongside the Class named Agenda_Temp which has the properties and DB connection assigned to it for each web form field.
    Dim oAgenda_Temp As New Agenda_Temp

    'Within the object Agenda_Temp Class use the properties defined. 
    'They are required to be defined in the Agenda_Temp/ app code so we can use them within here.

     With oAgenda_Temp
        .Organiser = txtOrganiser.Text
        .Meeting = txtMeeting.Text
        .AgendaDate = New SmartDate(txtAgendaDate.Text)


        'Within the object Agenda_Temp class use the defined DAL which includes all the DC connect and stored procedures.  
        oAgenda_Temp.AgendaID = Agenda_TempDAL.AddAgenda_Temp(oAgenda_Temp)
    End With

End Sub
End Class
```

I understand that its telling me that the string value cannot be converted to a date but i don't know hoe to resolve this as i am new to .net 2010?

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc165448.aspx

Comment: Where's the constructor of `SmartDate` that takes a string? You've shown so much code, why have you left out the relevant part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the string to a date before newing it:
From MSDN:

```
string date = "01/08/2008";
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(date);
```

Your's would become

```
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(txtAgendaDate.Text)
```

Then pass the date to your `SmartDate` constructor:

```
oAgenda_Temp.AgendaDate = new SmartDate(dt)
```

The final result:

```
  With oAgenda_Temp
        .Organiser = txtOrganiser.Text
        .Meeting = txtMeeting.Text
        .AgendaDate = New SmartDate(Convert.ToDateTime(txtAgendaDate.Text))


        'Within the object Agenda_Temp class use the defined DAL which includes all the DC connect and stored procedures.  
        oAgenda_Temp.AgendaID = Agenda_TempDAL.AddAgenda_Temp(oAgenda_Temp)
    End With
```

Comment: The same here: how do you know that the constructor of SmartDate takes a DateTime as parameter? Then it would not even compile. Edit: Maybe `option strict` is _off_ what is always a bad idea.

Comment: @ JonH.  This conversion worked a treat and accepts the selected date and populates this into the database.  Many Thanks All.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, you need to convert the input value to a `DateTime`. I don't know what the `SmartDate()` function is doing, but the error message clearly indicates that the value cannot be converted to a date.

Secondly, I would add some validation to make sure that the input is valid before you submit the page. Use the `RequiredFieldValidator` and `CompareValidator` or `RegularExpressionValidator`:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server" ... />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqDate" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Required" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtDate"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regDate" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtDate" ErrorMessage="Please enter a valid date in the format (mm/dd/yyyy)" ValidationExpression="^(0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)\d\d$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```